# Как передать функцию в качестве аргумента в другую функцию PHP

Tags: php, функции

Если есть две функции например

```
function one($arg) {
 $arg()
}

function two() {
 echo "Что-нибудь"
}

one(two())
```

Каким образом это можно сделать?

Comment: Вы вроде уже передали, нет?)

Comment: Нет, это он ее вызвал и передал аргументом результат вызова.

Comment: В руководстве https://www.php.net/manual/ru/functions.variable-functions.php#functions.variable-functions Для твоего случая `one('two')`

Answer (score 3):

В качестве аргумента можно передать либо имя обычной функции,

```
function one($arg) {
    return $arg();
}

function two() {
    return "Что-нибудь\n";
}

$function = 'two';
echo one($function);
```

либо анонимную функцию

```
$function = function() {
    return "Что-нибудь\n";
};
echo one($function);
```

Но так заморочиваться приходится довольно редко, а обычно достаточно просто передавать во вторую функцию результат работы первой